# How to implement draggable magnetic like floating action button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, floating-action-button

How can I implement dragging magnetic like floating action bar in android which is similar to quick ball in MI or Xiaomi devices or in iOS devices? Gallery of Mi device's too have this.
What I want

1. It can be draggable fab
2. It is like magnetic which means if it is on the left half of the screen and you leave it, it moves to left and same for the right, it moves to right
3. On clicking it, it expands in circular direction of more buttons
4. (Optional)it becomes translucent after some amount of seconds on inactivity

5.(Optional)it becomes an arrow after some more time approx. 10 seconds on inactivity

If you want any type of video or image reference you can easily just google **Quick ball in MI devices**.

I can't find any of the questions like this, although they had some similarities but not like what I wanted, if you find it please answer the link to it.

Thanks a lot.